# understanding the difference between pointer dereference and array indexing

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dereference, pointer-arithmetic

In the code below could somebody explain why `sum += *(ptr+i);` is the same as `sum += ptr[i];`?

I understand that `sum += *(ptr+i);` is dereferencing the memory address and then summing the numbers?

But in `sum += ptr[i];` there is no deference...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int len, i, sum;
    printf("Enter how many numbers you want to sum:");
    scanf("%d", &len);
    int* ptr;
    ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * len);
    for(i=0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("Enter a number:");
        scanf("%d", ptr+i);
    }
    for(i=0; i < len; i++) {
    //sum += *(ptr+i);
      sum += ptr[i];    
    }
    printf("The sum is %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By the definition (the C Standard, 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
>   (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
>   E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

Thus these three statements

```
sum += *(ptr+i);
sum += ptr[i];    
sum += i[ptr];
```

are equivalent.

Take into account that the program has undefined behavior because the variable `sum` was not initialized.:) To avoid an overflow it would be better to declare it like

```
long long int sum = 0;
// ...
printf("The sum is %lld\n", sum);
```

Comment: is the 3rd option a common one?

Comment: @CIsForCookies It is better not to use it because it can confuse readers.:)

Comment: that's why I asked :) Never seen it before and it seemed unnatural to me, compared to the previous 2

Answer (score 1):

It's the same simply because that's how the language works. And yes, the `[]` indexing operator really does dereference the pointer to its left, it has to do that in order to get the value.

In C in general, `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a + b)`.

This leads to the fun classic like

```
printf("%c\n", 4["foobar"]);
```

The above prints `a`, since `*(4 + "foobar")` is the same as `*("foobar" + 4)`, i.e. `"foobar"[4]`.

Answer (score 0):

> But in `sum += ptr[i]` there is no deference

There is no dereference only in the sense that the dereference operator `*` is not used. However, dereference is still there, because index operator `[]` in C is an equivalent of `*`: the two are completely interchangeable in all situations. When you see `x[i]` you can rewrite it as `*(x+i)`, and vice versa.

The ability to rewrite a dereference of an addition as index expression results in one of the least readable constructs in C grammar - an ability to rewrite `x[i]` as `i[x]`.

Answer (score 0):

`ptr[i]` evaluates to `*(ptr + i)`
Actual increment depends on the type of pointer

If `ptr` is `int`, an increment ie `ptr + 1` will increment the address by 4(assuming int is 4 bytes) memory locations ie (if `ptr` is 0xFF000005 `ptr+1` will be 0xFF000009)

If `ptr` is `char`, an increment ie `ptr + 1` will increment the address by 1 memory locations (if `ptr` is 0xFF000005 `ptr+1` will be 0xFF000006)

Answer (score 0):

`sum += *(ptr+i);` here initially the index value "i" is added to the "ptr", then after dereferencing the array pointer to get the value. It is added to the "sum"

`sum += ptr[i];`here directly accessing the value through its index value "i" from array "ptr". It is added to the "sum"